# How to deploy Azure Container Instance to VNET using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I need to deploy Azure Container Instance with VNet connection using Azure CLI.
Here's the command I'm using:

```
az container create -g My_RG --name ubuntu-aci-2 --image ubuntu --vnet /subscriptions/f2ees954-606e-4480-b05f-48c85c8c05cf/resourceGroups/My_RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/aci-vnet --subnet default
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Resource /subscriptions/f2ees954-606e-4480-b05f-48c85c8c05cf/resourceGroups/My_RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/ACI-VNET referenced by resource /subscriptions/f2ees954-606e-4480-b05f-48c85c8c05cf/resourceGroups/My_RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles/aci-network-profile-aci-vnet-default was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region

What am I doing wrong?

// EDIT

The VNET "aci-vnet" and its subdomain "default" already exist before creating the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should deploy the container instance in the region that is the same as the Vnet in the region.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I am able to successfully deploy the container when using the Azure Portal (with the same settings).

Comment: Could you double-check? On the Azure portal, I only could select the VNet in the region which is the same as the region where the container instance will deploy.

Comment: Ha, looks like you were right. The thing I missed was the "--location". It looks like by default it was deploying to US East, which a different region that my VNET.

Answer (score 0):

The subnet you deploy to should also not have any other resources assigned to the same subnet or the deployment will fail.

Microsoft guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#deploy-to-existing-virtual-network